# Catch ctrl-C and Set value

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing a robot and I wrote some programs for that robot. In the robot's **motor driving node**, I  subscribed the topic from `/cmd_vel` topic. What the current issue is that when the motor is running and if I terminate the **motor driving node** with `ctrl-C`,  the motor is still running.

Is there any way to put the motor values with `0` before terminating the program? I am using `ROS melodic`  with `python` as the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ........

class main():
    def __init__(self):
         rospy.init_node("robot", anonymous=False)
         rospy.Subscriber(..........)
         self.pub=rospy.Publisher(..........)

         rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(0.2), self.main_callback)
         while not rospy.is_shutdown():
              rospy.sleep(0.2)
              print("-----------------")
    
     def main_callback(self, event):
           ......................
           motor_1 = 50
           ....end.....

if __name__="__main__":
          try: main()
          except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

As with this example, some way to set the value `motor_1=0` before terminating the node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366785/catch-ctrl-c-and-set-value/) by [yanaing](https://answers.ros.org/users/53445/yanaing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could register a hook with `rospy.on_shutdown()` as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Registering_shutdown_hooks), that sets the motor values to zero. Note that, as described, messages aren't guaranteed to be published.

If you need more fancy handling, have a look at the Advanced Example on the same page.

Also, note that if your node crashes for some reason, this will not be called.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Combinacijus](https://answers.ros.org/users/44007/combinacijus/) on 2023-01-20**:
Thanks solved my problem. Normal class destructor **del**() is called but it seems that rospy is already shutdown by that point so you can't publish anything. Meanwhile your method `rospy.on_shutdown(self.my_function)` calls `my_function()` before rospy is shutdown and it's able to publish